# Finding tag by xpath by a text that has an inner tag inside

Tags: selenium, xpath

I've recently come across an issue.

I need to find a div tag on a page, that contain specific text. The problem is, that text is divided into two parts by an inner link tag, so that an HTML tree would look like:

```
**<html>
    <...>
    <div>
        start of div text - part 1
        <a/>
        end of div text - part 2
    </div>
    <...>
</html>**
```

To uniquely identify that div tag I'd need two parts of div text. Naturally, I would come up with something like this XPath:

```
.//div[contains(text(), 'start of div text') and contains(text(), 'end of div text')]
```

However, it doesn't work, the second part can not be found.

What would be the best approach to describe this kind of tag uniquely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use below XPath to match required `div` by two text nodes:

```
//div[normalize-space(text())="start of div text - part 1" and normalize-space(text()[2])="end of div text - part 2"]
```

Comment: That's awesome !

Comment: @Andersson : Not an efficient solution IMO, what would happen if I had text split in 3 or 4 division. Don't we have to write text()[2] , text()[3] , text()[4] and so on..

Comment: @cruisepandey , we can imagine most incredible situations... but OP said *"...text is divided into two parts"* and shared HTML code sample reflects the same

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. You simply need to replace the `text()` with **`.`** as follows:

```
//div[contains(., 'start of div text') and contains(., 'end of div text')]
```

Here is the snapshot of the validation :

[image: xpath_tester]

Comment: I like your solution, the result XPath looks clean and simple. However, if we have another enclosing <div> tag around our target tag, then the enclosing one would be found by this XPath instead of the enclosed one, the one we're looking for.

Comment: @Alex.K If you have another `<div>` of-coarse the _xpath_ would change. In my answers I always try to preserve OP's innovation. It's your decision to choose the most helpful answer :) All the best !!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
//div[contains(text(), 'start of div text') and contains(./a/text(), 'end of div text')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have HTML DOM tree like this :

```
<div id="container" class="someclass">
    <div>
        start of div text - part 1
        <a/>
        end of div text - part 2
    </div>
 </div>
```

for extracting div text, you can write xpath like this :

```
//div[@id='container']/child::div
```

P.S : Writing xpath based on text to find the same exact text is not a good way to write Xpath.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is plenty of divs on target page with same ids and attributes, so using @id is not an option in my case.

Comment: Well, you should know how to differentiate between multiple divs. The current solution you have from andersson will work for only 2 text divsion. As I stated earlier your xpath should not contain the exact text which is present in UI. If the text changes in UI , then you will have to change the xpath which is unnecessary to do.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the `div` element of those child text elements, then you could isolate a piece of unique content from "part 1" and try the following:

`//*[contains(., 'part 1')]/parent::div`

This way you wouldn't have to think about the `div`'s attributes.

However, this is usually **not** best practice.  Ideally, you should use the following Xpath in most cases:

`//div[@id,('some id') and contains(., 'part 1')]`